# Clojure: using Spark factory method with Java interop

Tags: java, clojure, apache-spark

I think this is a Java interop question, but perhaps it's a nuance of Spark (or failing to import something from Scala?). I am trying to follow along with the example [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html). It includes the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;
Vector dv = Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0, 3.0);
```

My first thought was this:

```
(import '[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg Vector Vectors])
(Vectors/dense 1.0 0.0 3.0)
```

But I get:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method: dense, compiling:(/tmp/form-init6598386874684927469.clj:1:1)
```

I tried:

```
(.dense (Vectors. 1.0 0.0 3.0))
```

and got:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors, compiling:(/tmp/form-init6598386874684927469.clj:1:9)
```

I've tried a variety of additional combinations (vectors, Java arrays, the `..` macro, etc.), but can't get it to work. In particular, even though the documentation shows a constructor that takes no arguments (*see* [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vector.html)), nothing like `(Vectors.)` seems to work (a `No matching ctor`) error. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `(Vectors/dense (double-array [1.0 0.0 3.0]))`? I didn't test this myself but it should match the `Vector dense (double[] values)` method in [Vectors](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vectors.html).

Comment: That worked&mdash;thanks! I didn't realize that the type of an array was defined by anything besides its contents. And I didn't realize that the `double-array` function existed. But the results of `into-array` vs `double-array` have different types: `[D` and `[Ljava.lang.Double`, respectively.